# About MOSFET circuit behavior

Tags: mosfet, circuit-analysis, circuit-design, analog, integrated-circuit

When I look at the waveforms of simulated circuits, how do I know when their behavior (for example flipping value stored on a node, or an unexpected drop in strong level value...) is due to MOSFET leakage mechanisms/ slightly open transistor/ charge injection/ clock feedthrough etc... ?

Thanks

Comment: Experience in a word. Trying things out. Investigating. Brainstorming. Imagination. 2nd opinion. Mentoring. Training but, overall experience.